# Android, runnable message queuing error

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I am a beginner to android trying to use the following runnable in the onResume() method of my app to plot a realtime signal which my app receives from a bluetooth connected sensor. the sensor sends a high frequency signal of 200hz which is 5ms delay and I have a serialReceive method on my main thread which receives the bluetooth data. My graphview data is updated in this method and also included is a stream writer code which stores the data to SD card. Now my problem is when I send the high frequency data, the app stops working. When I tried to identify the problem its within this runnable because all the others are working. I tried to use the postDelayed method at the end (mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer1, 5);) but its not working either. Note that the runnable also works if i use a low freq signal input of like 20hz (50ms delay).

```
 mTimer1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {         
        GraphViewData[] gvd = new GraphViewData[seriesX.size()];                
        seriesX.toArray(gvd);
        Series.resetData(gvd);

        mHandler.post(this);
    }

    };

    mHandler.post(mTimer1);
```

FYI, Here is the method I receive the serial data from

```
@Override
public void onSerialReceived(String theString) {                            

ecgSensor = Double.parseDouble(theString);
seriesX.add(new GraphViewData(dataCount, ecgSensor));


textOut.add(new String(String.valueOf(dataCount) + " " + theString + lineSep));
printable = textOut.toString();

try {

    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    OutputStreamWriter myWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
    myWriter.append(printable);
    myWriter.flush();
    myWriter.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} 

dataCount++;

if (seriesX.size() > 250) {
    seriesX.remove(0);
    graphView.setViewPort(dataCount - 250, 250);
}
```

}

Any help on how to solve this is appreciated.
Many thanks,

Comment: Why are you using `mHandler.post(this)` in the runnable? Try to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks @Romadja , I am using it to update my graphview and without it the graph will not plot in real time. removing it also stops the program.

Comment: What does "the app stops working" mean? Does it crash? If so, with what error or exception?

Otherwise, it looks like your app is working exactly as you'd like. 200 times per second, you are updating a graph (actually 400 since your runnable posts itself in addition to getting posted by what I assume is the onResume code.

Comment: Also, having the runnable post itself every time it runs is a recipe for trouble. You've just created an infinite loop which should result in your application running very sluggishly.

Why isn't the runnable posted when you receive new data? Why do you do it in onResume? There are some design issues that need to  be addressed here.